# Using a regex to query the Rails cache to allow partial matches and return multiple items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, caching

In brief i'm writing a plugin for a Rails app and I want to cache the data the plugin generates, however I want the ability to delete the cached items should I need to do so.

e.g.

```
Rails.cache.write("data_1", "the data")
Rails.cache.write("data_2", "the data")
Rails.cache.write("data_3", "the data")
```

What should I be calling to fetch all keys that match the regex /^data_/ so I can delete them?

I tried:

```
Rails.cache.fetch(/^data_/)
Rails.cache.read(/^data_/)
```

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.match`. So something like this should work:

```
if Rails.cache.fetch(..).match(/^data_/)
  do something
```

Comment: I was over complicating things and my Rails book is outdated, it seems there is a method:http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-delete_matched

Comment: @AnkitSoni This is giving a syntax error Rails.cache.fetch(..).match(/^data_/)